# Simple If statement not working (BlueJ)

Tags: java, bluej

I am working on a simple self-checkout for school and i have no clue why this doesn't work, i have tried everything.
I want the remove last item method to only work if the boolean variable is true. having the boolean be false means it will not work and come up with a printed error message. so far no matter what the value of the boolean, the remove last item method still "removes" in a sense as it decreases the count of items by 1. once the print receipt method is called it resets both count and the boolean value so that you cannot remove an item if there is none. However it still makes the count value -1. the remove item method is only intended to only work once (meaning you cannot remove an item then another item straight up), so if you attempt to remove an item after you already just did there should be an error message printed to the terminal, but the supposed error message just does not print at all.

```
public class Machine
{
private double balance;
private int count;
private boolean lastEntry;
private double itemPrice;

public Machine()
{
    balance = 0;
    count = 0;
    lastEntry = false;
}

public void scanItem(Item newItem)
{
   balance = balance + newItem.price;
   itemPrice = newItem.price;
   count = count + 1;
   lastEntry = true;
}

public void printReciept ()
{
   System.out.println ("####################");
   System.out.println ("Total = $" + balance); 
   System.out.println ("Number of Items = " + count);
   System.out.println ("Next Customer!");
   System.out.println ("####################");
   balance = 0;
   count = 0;
   lastEntry = false;
}  

public void removeLast ()
{
  if (lastEntry = false) {
      System.out.println ("CANNOT PERFORM ACTION");

    }else if (lastEntry = true){
     balance = balance - itemPrice;
     count = count - 1;
     lastEntry = false;
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: `=` is for assigning a value, you want `==` to make a comparison .

Comment: or, better yet, replace it with: if ( !lastEntry)

Answer (score 1):

`=` operator does *assignment*, not comparision. You should use `==` operator to test equality.

In this case, you can simply write like this:

```
public void removeLast ()
{
    if (!lastEntry) { // ! operator means logical negation
        System.out.println ("CANNOT PERFORM ACTION");
    } else { // !lastEntry is false, so lastEntry must be true
        balance = balance - itemPrice;
        count = count - 1;
        lastEntry = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: He could also write `balance -= itemPrice;` and `count--;` as improvements :)

Answer (score 0):

You have used incorectly the `=` operator. Note:

- `=` stands for **assignment**
- `==` stands for **comparison** of `int`, `double` etc.
- `equals(..)` stands for **comparison** of `String` or others..

So your code should look like this:

```
if (lastEntry == false) {
    System.out.println ("CANNOT PERFORM ACTION");
} else if (lastEntry == true){
    balance = balance - itemPrice;
    count = count - 1;
    lastEntry = false;
}
```

You can make it shorter with `!` and `--` and `-=` operators:

```
if (!lastEntry) { // is false
    System.out.println ("CANNOT PERFORM ACTION");
} else { // else if true
    balance -= itemPrice;
    count--;
    lastEntry = false;
}
```